# Assetic automatic cache busting without query?

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I couldn't find much information on this.

I want to compile all css (and js indeed) files into something like this:

```
css/all-c498dsfbc.css
```

Right now I'm only able to get these:

```
css/all.css
css/c498dsfbc.css
css/all.css?v=123
```

The first one sucks, because it has no cache busting at all.

The second one generates a hash which could be used for cache busting, but for some reason it doesn't change when I change something in my .css files and then run again this:

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

The third one sucks too because I'm required to change the version manually, as explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ref-framework-assets-version. Also, I don't think using queries for this is a good idea (I think some browsers or CDN might not like that). It would be much better if the filename was changed: 'all-c498dsfbc.css'. This is how it's done in Rails if I remember correctly.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Seem like this feature is missing, I can't believe it: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/pull/190

Comment: The second one doesn't change, b/c assetic uses the filenames instead of the content to generate it's hash. I'm looking for the same thing and it looks like there is already something build into 1.1 - https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/116 . I will try to get it working. Using versionnumbers and update it on every change sucks :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In our project to ensure that new content won't be cached by Varnish for each deployment we manually change version - and assets pick that one. I think, it is a common practice. But in our case - it saves it in folder such as `web/version-1.2.3/css/all.css`.

Our config for `framework` section:

```
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        assets_version: %release_version%
        assets_version_format: "version-%%2$s/%%1$s"
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm still thinking what my workflow should be like. Am I supposed to generate 'version-1.2.3/css/all.css' locally and add it to my vcs repository, and have it deployed along with any other changes? Or only generate it the production server? I'll wait to see what others think about changing assets version manually, I'm not comfortable with the idea of having to remember to do that. I was thinking that I could add this to the capifony recipe 'php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug' and be done with this. But changing config files on each deployment is a different story.

Comment: The idea is that for release you always change the version of your application. And assets just pick that parameter. If you still don't have parameter for version of your application - you should definitely start thinking about it. Not only for assets :) For rpms names, for checking if the right version was deployed and so on.
As for deployments - all our applications have build script, which removes tests, generate assets, makes assetic dump and so on. So at the end you provide the deployer only with rpm file, which contains all your files. 
Again - having application version is good practice

Comment: I ended up writing my own deployment script to do this your way, now I know bash =D. But now I have a more basic problem: How do you make assetic dump the assets with the version? It does not seem to work. I posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895299/how-to-prepend-assets-version-to-css-and-js

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but it is at the top of Google so I thought it worth the update:

You can now do this with assetic using the [cache buster worker](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Factory/Worker/CacheBustingWorker.php).  However the 2.3.0 assetic bundle does not have the config for it so you need to manually enable it for now.  This can be done will the following service definition:

```
#config.yml or a service.yml
#...
services:
    assetic.worker.cache_buster:
        class: Assetic\Factory\Worker\CacheBustingWorker
        public: false
        arguments:
            lazy_manager: @assetic.asset_manager
        tags:
            worker_factory: { name: assetic.factory_worker }
```

This work around is from the pull request for the configuration of the cache buster worker: https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/pull/119/files