# How to prepend assets version to css and js?

Tags: php, caching, symfony, twig, assetic

I want assetic to output compressed js and css to something like this:

`v2.3.1/css/whatever.css`

Currently this is how I dump my css and js for production: `$ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`. But they get dumped into css/ and js/, without the version.

I have read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-version) but it seems to refer to images only, not css/js.

An important reason for doing this is for cache busting/invalidation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, known issue... In our production workflow we ended up with such block in `bin/vendors` script:

```
if (in_array('--env=dev', $argv)) {
    system(sprintf('%s %s assets:install --symlink %s', $interpreter, escapeshellarg($rootDir . '/app/console'), escapeshellarg($rootDir . '/web/')));
    system(sprintf('%s %s assetic:dump --env=dev', $interpreter, escapeshellarg($rootDir . '/app/console')));
    system(sprintf('%s %s myVendor:assets:install --symlink ', $interpreter, escapeshellarg($rootDir . '/app/console')));
} else {
    system(sprintf('%s %s assets:install %s', $interpreter, escapeshellarg($rootDir . '/app/console'), escapeshellarg($rootDir . '/web/')));
    system(sprintf('%s %s assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug', $interpreter, escapeshellarg($rootDir . '/app/console')));
    system(sprintf('%s %s myVendor:assets:install ', $interpreter, escapeshellarg($rootDir . '/app/console')));
}
```

As you can see, we defined our console command, which installs assets into web folder after installing and dumping of Symfony's assets. In the `MyVendorCommand` script we do something like this:

```
$version = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('your_version_parameter');
$assetsInstallCommand = $this->getApplication()->find('assets:install');

$commandOptions = $input->getOptions();

$assetsInstallArguments = array(
    'command' => 'assets:install',
    'target' => 'web/version-' . $version,
    '--symlink' => $commandOptions['symlink']
);

$assetsInstallInput = new ArrayInput($assetsInstallArguments);
$returnCode = $assetsInstallCommand->run($assetsInstallInput, $output);
```

Comment: Oh I see. Well I don't know much about sf2 internals, and also I'm using v2.1 so bin/vendors is gone. But you gave an idea and it worked: I added the symlink creation part to my deployment script (`vXXX/css -> css` and `vXXX/js -> js`). Thanks again! =)

Answer (score 1):

Ho, its a big Symfony2 bug ! I am not sure anyone reported it !

My solution was to add an alias in the Nginx config, but your is def. cleaner & better.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to make a rewriteRule in .htaccess file in order to serve the real file, but accepting the full url with version number. Something like this ...

## app/config/config.yml

```
[...]
engines: ['twig']
assets_version: 20140523  # numeric version
assets_version_format: "assets-%%2$s/%%1$s"
[...]
```

## web/.htaccess

```
[...]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^assets-([0-9]*)/(.*)$ ./$2 [L]
[...]
```